# Operations on Sets of Sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Given the following *union* operations over the sets, and sets of sets. I have doubts whether these are solved correctly. Please give me some explanation as counter example.

1. $\{\{a\} \cup \{\varnothing\}\} \cup \varnothing   = \mathbf{\{\{a\}\}}$
2. $\{\{a\} \cup \{\varnothing\}\} \cup \{\varnothing\} = \mathbf{\{\{a\}, \varnothing\}}$

Comment: I have solved the UNION operations over the set. Please tell me if these are correct.

Comment: I changed $\{\}$ to $\varnothing$ for better readability. I hope it is ok. It would be easier for us to help you when *you* explain to *us* how you derived these formulas instead us showing how *not* to derive them.

Comment: They are both incorrect.

Comment: Thanks. It looks good now.

Comment: @quallenjäger Incorrect too.

Comment: Now, I am sure they are both correct. But I need some explainations

Comment: @Eid Believe us, they are both incorrect. First ones right side is $\{\{a,\varnothing\}\}$. Second ones right side is $\{\{a,\varnothing\},\varnothing\}$.

Comment: Can you please give the correct answers for both of them. I have algorithms that give these answers.

Comment: @Eid I gave them in my comment above. Also please use tagging because otherwise no one gets notified when you answer to a comment.

Comment: @M.Winter. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct answer are given bellow along with their explanation:

1. $\{\{a\} \cup \{\varnothing\}\} = \{\{a\}, \{\varnothing\}\} and  \{\{a\}, \{\varnothing\}\} \cup \varnothing = \{\{a\}, \{\varnothing\}\}$
2. $\{\{a\} \cup \{\varnothing\}\} = \mathbf{\{\{a\}, \varnothing\}} and \{\{a\}, \{\varnothing\}\} \cup \{\varnothing\} = \{\{\{a\}, \{\varnothing\}\}, \varnothing\}$